# Primefaces Dialog is not displayed for the second time

Tags: jsf, dialog, primefaces

I'm working with Primefaces.My functionality is to display the records in a datatable with primefaces inline editing .Here we have an "Add" button which displays a dialog to enter new record.After entering the values and click on "Save" button,the record is inserted and the datatable is updated with the record.
   My problem is, when i click on "Add" button for the second time the dialog box is not opening.Here is my code.

```
        <h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">
    <p:dataTable  var="client" id="clientTable" value="#{clientView.clientModelList}" paginatorPosition="top"  paginator="true" rows="10"  
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,25" rowEditListener="#{clientView.rowEditListener}" onRowEditUpdate="growl" >

            <p:column style="width:60px;">              
            <p:rowEditor/> 
            <h:commandButton  style="padding-left:5px;" image="/resources/images/delete.jpeg" styleClass="spa"  value="delete" immediate="true" actionListener="#{clientView.delete}" >
                <f:attribute name="username" value="#{client}" />
            </h:commandButton>

            </p:column>

            <p:column>

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{myLoginBean.multilangMap['everis.client.idCliente']}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{client.codCliente}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.idClienteEmpty}" maxlength="80"  value="#{client.codCliente}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column>

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{myLoginBean.multilangMap['everis.client.desCliente']}" />
                </f:facet>

                <p:cellEditor>

                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{client.desCliente}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.desClienteEmpty}" maxlength="255"  value="#{client.desCliente}" />
                    </f:facet>

                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>
        </div>
        <div class="divButPosition">

        <h:panelGroup id="buttonPanel">

            <p:commandButton id="buttons" value="Add" actionListener="#{clientView.addEmptyClient}"
            async="true" update="buttonPanel,dlgForm:table"  rendered="#{!clientView.addNewRow}" oncomplete="alert('complete');clientDialog.show();" />

        </h:panelGroup>

    </div>
    </h:form>   
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" />  
<p:dialog id="clientDialog"  header="Client Detail"  widgetVar="clientDialog" resizable="false" width="500" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" modal="false" closable="false">
    <h:form id="dlgForm" > 

<h:dataTable var="newclient" id="table" value="#{clientView.newClient}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{myLoginBean.multilangMap['everis.client.idCliente']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{newclient.codCliente}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.idClienteEmpty}"  maxlength="80"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{myLoginBean.multilangMap['everis.client.desCliente']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{newclient.desCliente}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.desClienteEmpty}"   maxlength="255"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable> 
<p:commandButton value="everis.save"  actionListener="#{clientView.saveClient}" async="true" update="growl,buttonPanel,clientTable" oncomplete="handleRequest(args ,document.getElementById('clientDialog'))" />
<p:commandButton value="#{myLoginBean.multilangMap['everis.cancel']}" immediate="true" update="buttonPanel,table" async="true"  actionListener="#{clientView.cancelClient}" oncomplete="clientDialog.hide();" />
    </h:form>  
</p:dialog>
```

Thanks alot for every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now correct me if i'm wrong, but if you click save on the dialog you never close it? I won't know if it will help but you can try atleast

Comment: It's a great help Rafael.We are not closing the dialog,we are making the dialog to hide using js.When we use dialogName.hide(); it is working fine.We are facing another problem, the dialog is not showing for the first time now.Afer deleting a record from the datatable i mean page is reload then after clicking the Add it is showing the dialog.

Comment: The first time you load the page, check if you can actually see the dialog in the source code somewhere. Primefaces can bug alot with dialogs, there are a few unwritten rules you need to follow. Like never stick them in forms, don't update the dialog but the contents in it. Don't stick dialogs in renders...  I always place my dialogs on top so i know for sure they are not dependent on anything and i know that they are loaded first.

Comment: Yes Rafael, there are alot of issues.But i'm suffering from other problem.If i entered some values in the dialog and click on "cancel" button in the dialog will close the lightbox in the actionListener of cancel button i'm making the object to null.But when i click on "Add" button then again the old values are displaying.could anything is there to refresh the data in the dialog.

Comment: Ha! Funny stuff, i used primefaces inline editor for changing the e-mail value's in a table, when i click on it and leave it out it sais cannot be null puts the old value back and thats it... when i add something like lalala and i get a rexeg mistake saying: This is not an email if i click cancel it just adds the lalala instead of the old value. I've written something on the forums of primefaces asking if this is a bug, but they never awnsered : http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11523

Comment: And i'm guessing your going to set the bean values to null and refresh the form in the dialog before you show them

Comment: Hi Rafael, another problem arises.First time the dialog box is not opening,after making an edit or delete operations in the main form datatable.After that when click on "Add" button dialog is displaying.I don't know everyday a new problem in the primefaces dialog box.

Comment: I'm getting the following error:ERROR [application] Error Rendering View[/technology.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2301)

Comment: Hmmmm, thats something i haven't come across sorry :(